# Images won't display

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am having some problems getting my app to display images from the web.
It workes fine in my sample data as can be seen:

[image: fine]

But one the app runs on the emulate do i get this, you can see the link in the textbox:

[image: bad]

This is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```xml
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="105" Width="432">
            <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
            <Image>
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Image}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
            <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="8,-7,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Image}" FontSize="10" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GcwxIpl.png]

Comment: The image sources are absolute Internet addresses? Make sure the Internet works at all in the emulator and also the capability "ID_CAP_NETWORKING" must be enabled in your app manifest.

Comment: Show us how do you download images.

Comment: @MartinSuchan Yes, and it is on the internet as it download the list of characters from a website.

Comment: @AntonSizikov I don't, i just provide a path, they way i have made the image object should support that!

Comment: I recive NotFound error when I'm trying to download that images (http://img7.anidb.net/pics/anime/136529.jpg) from my WP emulator.

Comment: @AntonSizikov i don't know where you got that link from, but the links in the image is http://img7.anidb.net/pics/anime/54893.jpg

Comment: I got the link from your screenshot :)

Comment: @AntonSizikov http://i.imgur.com/h9Hh6ZQ.png the link is working fine for me?

Comment: Try the code from my answer. Put it into new Windows Phone app. Do you have an exeption?

Comment: And yes, sometimes it doesn't work for me, even from Google Chrome :) http://i.imgur.com/6AmbA3d.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason you can see your images is that your code fails to download them.
I just created a simple app for windows phone to download images manually (just to see what exactly is going on?).

The code is pretty straightforward:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
  <StackPanel>
     <Image>
       <Image.Source>
         <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Image}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
       </Image.Source>
     </Image>
      <Button Content="go" Click="ClickMe"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And the code-behinde:

```
    private void ClickMe(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var url = "http://img7.anidb.net/pics/anime/136529.jpg";
        var url = "http://img7.anidb.net/pics/anime/54893.jpg";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        //req.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        //req.Accept = "image/jpeg";
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.BeginGetResponse(Callback, req);
    }

    private void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.EndGetResponse(result);

            Stream myStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(myStream);
                var character = new Character();
                character.Image = bmp;
                ContentPanel.DataContext = character;
                //image1.Source = bmp;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I'm trying to download the image on WP I recive a webException with Stats code: `System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden`
BTW - sometimes I get this error when I'm trying to get the image using web browser. Not so often, but it happens. Most probably that website does not allow to get images.